# How to move plane icon with framer motion?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, css-animations, framer-motion

I have a react paper plane icon that I would like to make a cool effect by making it travel around the HTML document reaching the final position which is the menu button at the top.

This is how my react component called `NavPlane` looks like:

```
import React, { Component, useEffect } from "react";
import { useCycle } from "framer-motion";
import { FaPaperPlane } from "react-icons/fa";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

const PlaneVariants = {
  animationOne: {
    x: 370,
    y: 250,
    transition: { ease: [0.17, 0.67, 0.83, 0.67] },
  },
  animationTwo: {
    x: 140,
    y: 150,
    transition: { duration: 1.0 },
  },
  animationThree: {
    x: 170,
    y: 200,
    transition: { duration: 1.0 },
  },
};
export default function NavPlane() {
  const [animation, cycleAnimation] = useCycle(
    "animationOne",
    "animationTwo",
    "animationThree"
  );
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      cycleAnimation();
    }, 1000);
  }, []);
  return (
    <motion.div
      className="text-2xl text-gray-600"
      variants={PlaneVariants}
      animate={animation}
    >
      <FaPaperPlane />
    </motion.div>
  );
}
```

`cycleAnimation()` was supposed to cycle through 3 animations but only cycling through the first two. The 3rd is only applied when making some change to the code and updating it.

The final goal is to have a movement that goes from right corner of the page to middle, does a knot movement and then travels to the top of the page.

Any ideas how to make it cycle through as many animation variants as I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cycleAnimation` only advances one step. Initially it will start "animationOne". Once you call `cycleAnimation()` after 1 second, "animationTwo" will start. You need another timer if you want to play "animationThree"

```
useEffect(() => {
  setTimeout(cycleAnimation, 1000); // start "animationTwo" after 1 second
  setTimeout(cycleAnimation, 2000); // start "animationThree" after 2 seconds
}, []);
```